# Google Analytics - Search Traffic Segment count

Tags: google-analytics

From Behavior > All Pages, I added a segment (and checked the box Search Traffic). With this segment, GA reported like below. My question is: when a user landed on Page 1 from search, and then went to Page 2. Would his visit on Page 2 count as Search Traffic or not. I know it's counted as search traffic for Page 1, but how about Page 2 and any other pages after that for that matter?

Page 1:
All Users: 1000 // Search Traffic: 500

Page 2:
All Users: 100 // Search Traffic: 50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will count as search traffic for all the pages that a user visited during a session because the traffic source is a concept that applies at a session level and not at a hit / page level.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!